# Output loop one at a time rather than all at once?

Tags: php

I'm running PHP SOAP and the loop runs with 10 iterations. The issue I am having is that it will not output until the loop is complete, whereby displaying every output at once.
How can I have it output one at a time as it processes through the loop rather than all in one go after it completes the entire 10 loops?

```
<?php

$loops = 0; // set loops to 0

// connection credentials and settings
$location = 'https://theconsole.com/';
$wsdl = $location.'?wsdl';
$username = 'user';
$password = 'pass';

// include the console and client classes
include "class_console.php";
include "class_client.php";

// create a client resource / connection
$client = new Client($location, $wsdl, $username, $password);

while ($loops < 10)   
    {
    $dostuff;
    $echo "It has done: " .$stuff; // display output
    ob_end_flush(); ob_flush(); flush(); ob_start(); // added as per comments below - still not working
    }
?>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try [flush()](http://php.net/flush) command, also [ob_flush()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-flush.php) if dealing with output buffering

EDIT:
Seems to be an issue with the [sleep()](http://php.net/sleep) command, if you read in the comments (even the dev ones) it indicates that if sleep is called within a script, nothing will be output until after it's run. If you loop sleep calls you have to wait till the end of the loop.

Read the comment "mohd at Bahrain dot Bz 16-Dec-2009 09:12" that method does work, but you have to fill the buffer each time :(.

Comment: @Dov is your included classes using any type of frameworks? Zend Cake etc...? some sort of buffering is taking place that you need to remove. One other thing, try your page in a second and third browsers, as there are antivirus's that are installing toolbars/addons that do buffering and/or take over HTTP error codes (i.e 500 400)

Comment: @Viper_Sb: Both classes are only using public functions. I have tried in FF, IE and Chrome with addons disabled. Still no luck :/

Comment: @Dov well one thing to try is:     ob_end_flush();
    ob_flush();
    flush();
    ob_start(); one after another, but that shouldn't really be in any production stuff, but maybe it'll work.

Comment: @Viper_Sb: Appreciating the help! Updated code - still no luck.

Comment: @Viper_Sb: Thanks. Sleep removed, no difference.

Comment: @Viper_Sb: Not a problem, thanks for trying. I'll have a chat to someone running a similar method. Hopefully someone on stackoverflow can provide another solution as well. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [flush](http://php.net/manual/en/function.flush.php)

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably need to flush() and/or ob_flush() through each iteration if you want it to output each line as you get it.

Be advised, however, that this doesn't absolutely guarantee that you'll get each line as it becomes available, as teh web server may also be doing its own buffering too.

Answer (score 0):

(Tested under IEx and Firefox)

```
<?php
if (ob_get_level() == 0) ob_start();

for ($i = 0; $i<10; $i++){
        echo "<br> Line to show.";
        echo str_pad('',4096)."\n";  

        ob_flush();
        flush();
}
echo "Done.";
ob_end_flush();
?>
```

Use this code, this is working for me.